# Mosaic to new raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, mosaic

I am using ArcGIS Desktop.

I have 33 DEM tiles that I am trying to mosaic together using this tool, 
[image: DEM tiles]

but I keep getting strange results.

All of the DEM pixel depths/sizes are 32 bit float, 1 band and are in NAD83, which I have been specifying in the tool. I'm saving it to a gdb and not specifying a cellsize.  I am also leaving the mosaic operator and colormap modes as the defaults.  This is the result I am getting:

[image: mosaic_32bit]

Wondering if anyone knows why this is happening.

I tried using a mosaic dataset, but I am having issues with performing additional manipulation of it after I added all of the tiles.  I would prefer to use the mosaic to new raster as I know the additional analysis and manipulation I need to perform has worked in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, saving the output raster to a location outside of a gdb (in a regular folder) renders the correct result.  It can then be imported into a gdb with no problem.  [image: mosaic]